# How to show errors but still allow editing other rows in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm using `DataGrid` to show/edit data.
I want to allow user to edit multiple rows though some of them may have validation errors. Right now if some row has validation errors I cannot edit other rows.
I saw a solution where I need to use reflection to get some properties of the `DataGrid`. Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: no one knows how to do it?